# Fourier-style solutions to differential equations, not piecewise polynomials

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis

NDSolve returns piecewise polynomials. Is there any way I can get a 
single (non piecewise) function consisting of sines and cosines 
instead? Sort of a "Fourier approximation" to the solution of my 
differential equation?

One reason I dislike piecewise polynomials: regardless of order, some 
derivative must be discontinuous at the boundary of two pieces. This 
is unrealistic (ie, impossible) for physical phenomena.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Can you show an example where you could not differentiate InterpolatingFunction returned from `NDSolve`? But you could always find the Fourier series approximation of the InterpolatingFunction  returned  If this is what you want. It will not be any better than piecewise polynomials, due to Gibbs phenomenon to start with.

Comment: @Nasser I did see a related question about taking the Fourier transform of the resulting InterpolationFunction(s), but that seems a bit roundabout and inaccurate. I want the original solutions themselves in Sin and Cos functions. Re differentiation, I meant that InterpolationOrder 3 means the resulting polynomials are of 3rd degree, so their 3rd derivatives must be discontinuous at boundary points.

Comment: @Nasser is right, and I think the question is not specific enough. E.g., what are the boundary/initial conditions? We would need a minimal example to work with. Maybe one can rewrite the whole equation in Fourier space, but that depends on the details. If the spectrum is continuous, you won't gain anything in terms of simplicity of the output, I think.